# Setting maximum width for content in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, width

I have a jQuery Mobile webpage which currently has a `width=device-width` but my form elements (textfields and the submit button) stretch to the width of the browser when viewed on a desktop computer.

Is there any way to set a maximum width so that these elements (or the whole content div) display properly on mobile devices but don't exceed a fixed maximum width when viewed on desktop computers?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
    <style type='text/css'>
    <!--
        html { background-color: #333; }
        @media only screen and (min-width: 600px){
            .ui-page {
                width: 600px !important;
                margin: 0 auto !important;
                position: relative !important;
                border-right: 5px #666 outset !important;
                border-left: 5px #666 outset !important;
            }
        }
    -->
    </style>
```

The `@media only screen and (min-width: 600px)` restricts the CSS rule to desktop devices with a minimum window width of 600px. For these the `width` of the page container created by jQuery Mobile is fixed to 600px, `margin: 0 auto` centers the page. The rest improves the result aesthetically.

However, ther is one drawback: this doesn't really play well with the sliding animation. I suggest to disable the animation (maybe also depending on the media type and screen size using `@media`), because it looks just weird on a big screen anyways.

Comment: Thanks, sorry about the late acceptance, I didn't notice there was another answer. Would you possibly be able to edit your answer to explain how this solves the problem?

Comment: No problem. Another solution might be to just use `max-width` on the `.ui-page`. Not all browsers support `@media`.

Comment: @noah1989 hey, did you ever figure out a fix for the transition slide when doing this?  Thanks!

Comment: @user1040259 nope, I just disabled it. Note that the current Version of jqmobile uses the fade away transition by default because having to keep both pages in the DOM tree caused too much trouble anyways.

Comment: Any hints how to set maximum height? ```max-height: 320px !important;``` or ```height: 320px !important;``` does not work as expected... Any ideas?

Comment: If you are using a header or a footer you have to apply the width also to these parts: `.ui-header, .ui-footer {
    width: 600px !important;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
}`

Answer (score 3):

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 800px){
        body { 
            background:transparent !important; 
            overflow:hidden !important;
        }
        html {
            background: #fff;
            background-attachment: fixed;
            overflow:hidden !important;         
         }
        .ui-page {
            width: 340px !important;
            border:60px solid #111 !important;
            margin: 50px auto !important;
            position: relative !important;
            border-right: 20px #222 outset !important;
            border-left: 20px #000 outset !important;
            border-radius:25px;
            -webkit-border-radius:25px;
            -moz-border-radius:25px;
            overflow-y:scroll !important;
            min-height:600px !important;
            height:600px !important;
            max-height:600px !important;
            padding-bottom:0px;
        }

    }
```

Comment: I had the same question and the answer was very helpful, then I added some extra css and decided to share it. It's not all about getting acceptance :D

Answer (score 0):

```
.ui-page {
    max-width: 320px !important;/*or 640 */
    margin: 0 auto !important;
    position: relative !important;
}
```

Design and test for 320 px or 640 px.
in case of 640 px in desktop(bigger resolution) it will take a width of 640 px and on mobile it will be width of mobile.

give border if needed

```
.ui-page {
    border-right: 2px #000 outset !important;
    border-left: 2px #000 outset !important;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use `document.getElementById("id").style.width="200px";`

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Naning/VkyAv/7/)

Comment: That sets the width of the element. I want to set the max width. Using your code, when viewed on a mobile browser, the element doesn't shrink its width.