# Strange width of text-input in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I've come across a strange behavior related to the width of a text-input in jQuery Mobile - it simply is too big.

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Test</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <input type="text" value="192.168.1.1"></input>

        <a data-role="button">Connect</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

One can also reproduce this behavior by reducing the width of the browserwindow for example in jsFiddle.

**jsFiddle:** 
http://jsfiddle.net/QxYMa/

Is this the normal behavior or just a bug? How can I "correct" that, so that the text-input and the button have the same width?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The input and the button had some different CSS automatically applied to it. I added the following CSS which seemed to make the CSS visibly consistent for both of them:

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Test</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <input type="text" value="192.168.1.1" style="width:100%;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing: border-box;"/>
        <br/>
        <a data-role="button" style="width:100%;margin:0">Connect</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

It would appear that the input box-model was off, and the button margin was off. 
Here is a good article talking about box-model which seems to shed some light on this: http://www.jefftk.com/news/2012-02-18.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: I would replace the inline styles with classes.

Comment: Thanks! This is actually a really interesting article you have linked in your post. I've fixed two little typos in your code and it actually works - but somehow I think it's kind of "hackish". I'm going to wait a little while, maybe someone else has an even better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Right before my the start of my core jquery mobile structure.css I added a more complete  CSS reset.  This may help you.

```
/*  CSS Reset*/html,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,abbr,acronym,address,big,cite,code,del,dfn,em,font,img,ins,kbd,q,s,samp,small,strike,strong,sub,sup,tt,var,b,u,i,center,dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td  {margin:0;padding:0;border:0;outline:0; font-size:100%;vertical-align:baseline; background:transparent}body {line-height:1}ol,ul {list-style:none}blockquote,q {quotes:none}blockquote:before,blockquote:after,q:before,q:after{content:'';content:none}:focus {outline:0}ins {text-decoration:none}del {text-decoration:line-through}table {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0}
```

Comment: I've added it, and it doesn't help: http://jsfiddle.net/eKkjp/ - Anyway, where did you got your reset.css, I actually use Eric Meyer's one.

Comment: It's a modified version I found awhile back was originally based on Eric's. I believe I removed a few things I never tend to use.

Comment: You may also want to modify the input sizes directly. I do this with adding a class value to the ones I want to change size wise. Oddly I actually think some of them are too small - so I increased the height of them.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an example You could add a new theme. In the case below I added a theme F. Add more css to the theme and then call the data-theme="f" on your input element. You can then style it to your hearts content. One thing to note. You may need to use !important to override base sizes set by JQM.

```
.ui-bar-f input {
    font-family: 'HelveticaNeueLTStd55Roman', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    width:250px !important;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a working jsFidde with a device-size based width? Using a fixed width isn't an option for me.

Comment: Which device are you trying to target - you may just have to go with percentages - or a min-max depending on the device.

Comment: Mid- to High-End devices based on Android and later also iOS-Devices.

Comment: You're going to have use media queries to target your specific device sizes and than adjust these elements per each device. It's the nature of the beast if you want finite control over how these elements render on IPAD, kindle fire etc...

Comment: I've combined all answers and found a (at least for me) suitable solution - added it to my initial question. I'm now going to implement a max-width and center the whole content, so that it looks quite neat on each and every device. Thanks for your help!

Comment: The solution regarding the max-width can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7936119/setting-maximum-width-for-content-in-jquery-mobile - based on the media queries you have mentioned.

Comment: Hope it works out - I'm in the same boat:)

Answer (score 0):

Input fields just want to be full width.   Setting width:80px however will limit their width.  See this fiddle with lines of both normal and mini-sized versions.

http://jsfiddle.net/den232/WzH3Y/

```
    .floatleft {
    float:left;
 }
.floatright {
    float:right;
 }
.forceinline{  /* Prevent fieldcontain from doing a BLOCK thing */
    display:inline !important;
}
.textwidth {  /* limit width of input fields */
    width:80px;
}
.closespacing { /* controls spacing between elements */
    margin:0px 5px 0px 0px;
 }
.bigselect {   /* centers select with big buttons */
    padding: 0px;
    margin:2px 5px 0px 0px;
 }
.biginputheight {   /* matches text input height to big buttons */
    padding-top:10px !important;
    padding-bottom:12px !important;
}
.miniinputheight { /* matches text input height to minibuttons */
    padding-top:5px !important;
    padding-bottom:5px !important;
}
<div data-role="page" class="type-home">
```

```
<ul data-role="listview">
  <li  data-role="fieldcontain">first LI line</li>
  <li  data-role="fieldcontain">

    <div class='floatleft closespacing'>
        Big Buttons<br>More Text
    </div>


    <div  class='floatleft textwidth'>
      <input type="text" placeholder="left" class='biginputheight'></input>
    </div>  

    <div  class='floatright textwidth'>
      <input type="text" placeholder="right" class='biginputheight'></input>
    </div>  

  </li>
  <li  data-role="fieldcontain">

    <div class='floatleft closespacing'>    
        Small Buttons
    </div>


    <div  class='floatleft textwidth'>
      <input type="text" placeholder="e2" class='miniinputheight'></input>
    </div>  


    <div class='floatright closespacing'>
      <div  class='floatright closespacing'>    
        e3 Text<br>on right
      </div>
      <div  class='floatright textwidth'>
        <input type="text" placeholder="e3" class='miniinputheight'></input>
      </div>  
    </div>
  </li>
  <li  data-role="fieldcontain">last LI line</li>

</ul><!-- /listview -->
```

Comment: a lot things related to text-inputs have changed in the newest version of jquery mobile - therefore the question isn't relevant anymore, since it should work now. nevertheless has your answer nothing todo with the the original question in any way.